# PHP Intersect Mutlidimensional Array with Indexed Array

Tags: php, arrays, php-7, array-intersect

I am trying to intersect an multidimensional array with an indexed array and return matching sku's. Below are my array

```
$products=[
      {
      "id": "6",
      "sku": "a",  
   },
      {
      "id": "15",
      "sku": "b",
   },
      {
      "id": "16",
      "sku": "c",    
   },
      {
      "id": "17",
      "sku": "d",    
   },
      {
      "id": "18",
      "sku": "e",    
   }
]
$skus=[
   "a",
   "c",
   "e"
]
```

How do intersect both arrays and return `$products` array with matching items.
`array_intersect` does not provide expected results

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's not a correct PHP syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use **in_array** php function
Just like this

```
$products=json_decode($products,true);
$productsFinal='';
foreach ($products as $product){
    if(in_array($product['sku'],$skus)){
        $productsFinal[]= $product;
    }

}
```